# Atom text editor gone after update to 20.10, error: Depends: gvfs-bin but it is not installable

Tags: apt, atom

Today I succesfully upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10. However, I noticed that the Atom text editor that I use was gone after the update. So, I tried installing it using `sudo apt install atom`. That didn't work and threw the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 atom : Depends: gvfs-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does this mean that I upgraded to 20.10 too soon and that Atom does not support it yet? I tried a few things, like

- Reinstalling gvfs-bin;

  Package gvfs-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
  is only available from another source

  E: Package 'gvfs-bin' has no installation candidate
- apt clean, apt autoremove, apt install --fix-broken, apt install -f

Comment: I ran into exactly the same issue. can anyone help?

Comment: I ran into the same problem and for the time being, I started using 1.53 BETA. See this: https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `gvfs-bin` package has been dropped by Ubuntu in 20.10. It won't be added later. It won't be supported.

The reason is that it's deprecated. See the package description:

> This package contains deprecated command-line tools such as gvfs-copy
> and gvfs-rename. Please use the gio(1) tool in the libglib2.0-bin
> package instead.

Since there is no `atom` package in the Ubuntu repositories, there was no reason to keep `gvfs-bin`. Contact the upstream Atom project and let them know that their software has an obsolete dependency and is no longer installable.

The `gvfs-bin` package remains in all supported releases before and including 20.04. Consider remaining on 20.04, or running a 20.04 VM or Container.

Alternately, you can try [downloading](https://packages.ubuntu.com) the package and trying to install it on a newer system. However, that is unsupported. If you encounter problems, you're on your own. Our only advice will be to uninstall the wrong-version package.

...or you can skip all the deb dependencies entirely and [just install the Snap](https://snapcraft.io/atom) instead.

Comment: According to [this ticket in the Atom repository](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/21494), the problem has been fixed in the beta version of Atom 1.53. So the most sensible approach would probably be to wait until the final packages for Atom 1.53 are released and use those. Or, if you need the editor urgently and are willing to take the risks of using beta software, you can try the beta packages.

Answer (score 3):

Could not install atom 1.52.0 on ubuntu 20.10 either. Even the deb file from the site (atom.io) fails with *software install* with a (unspecified) software dependencies error. Here are two ways that do work for now :

```
snap install atom --classic
```

Or visit atom.io, download and install the [beta](https://atom.io/beta) version (1.53.0-beta0) using *software install*.

I opted for the beta.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is fixed in the beta builds

```
apt install atom-beta
```

**Edit**: before runnign the command above you have to add Atom PPA to your system. From the [official instructions](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/atom):

```
curl -sL https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then setup the repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: That command does not work on a base Ubuntu install. What repositories or PPA have you added?

Comment: @xiota: See https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#debian-and-ubuntu-debapt

Comment: The point is this answer is grossly incomplete.

Comment: I have grossly amended my original answer

Answer (score 2):

Today `atom` version **1.53.0** was released. The dependency to `gvfs-bin` package was removed in this version. This is explained in [the release notes](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.53.0) and [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/21425).

You can install the deb package as explained on [their web site](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/).

I removed the `atom-beta` package and installed the normal `atom` package. It works as expected.